# Is there a possibility I will get sent back from South Korea once I arrive after being in Wuhan December 2019?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, south-korea, event-based-effects, covid-19

On what grounds will a tourist be sent back from South Korea? Especially in the midst of the coronavirus 2019-nCoV? I’ve returned to Indonesia from China at the end of December, and have not shown any symptoms ever since. I plan to travel to South Korea some time this month. Is there a slightest possibility of me being sent back to Indonesia from the South Korean airport even after having my visa approved by the Korean embassy?

Answer (score 5):

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states:

> - Passengers who have been in the Hubei Province (China
>     People's Rep.) in the past 14 days are not allowed to enter
>     Korea (Rep.).

The end of December was more than 14 days ago, so you should be fine.